# Subscription stop after only a few blocks in Web3j

Tags: web3j

I am using the following code to catch and receive new transactions:

```
    DefaultBlockParameter startingBlock = DefaultBlockParameter.valueOf(lastActionedBlockNumber.add(BigInteger.ONE));

web3j.catchUpToLatestAndSubscribeToNewTransactionsObservable(startingBlock).subscribe(transaction -> {
        System.out.println("Processing transaction: " + transaction.getHash());

        //do processing
    });
```

When running this code against test geth it works totally fine.  However, when it is switched to the main block chain it will only execute one or two blocks then immediately unsubscribe itself.

These are my geth parameters:

Test:

```
geth --datadir node5 --network 1907 console --rpc --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3,personal" --rpcaddr localhost --rpcport 8545
```

Main:

```
geth --cache 2048 --rpc --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3,personal" --rpcaddr localhost --rpcport 8545
```

Comment: I am having the same problem. Any solution to this?

Comment: No idea why it doesn't work... I did a work around by first doing catchUpToLatestBlockObservable then following up with a blockObservable(true).subscribe